# Insert Multiple combobox into one Field in database

Tags: php, mysql

i has multiple combobox in my page, here's the code:

```
<select name="usulan[]" size="3" multiple>
<option name="satu" value="satu"> satu </option>
<option name="dua" value="dua"> dua </option>
<option name="tiga" value="tiga"> tiga </option>
<option name="empat" value="empat"> empat </option>
</select>
```

Then i check more than one option like this:

[image]

i want every option i check is inserted to one field (field_usulan) in my database.

so if i has table like this:

```
id | alat         | field_usulan
-----------------------------
1  |              |
```

after inserted, i want it to become something like this:

```
id | alat         | field_usulan
-----------------------------
1  | RJ45         | satu, dua
```

if i use this code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
    include "../conf/koneksi.php";
    $count = count($_POST['alat']);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
     if(!empty($_POST['alat'][$i]))
    {
      $alat             = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['alat'][$i]);
      $usulan           = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usulan'][$i]);
      $sql= "ALTER TABLE tb_inventaris AUTO_INCREMENT = 1";
      mysql_query($sql);
      $sql2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_inventaris (alat,usulan)
      VALUES
      ('$alat', '$usulan')") or die(mysql_error());
      echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"REFRESH\" CONTENT=\"0; URL='../koordinator.php?url=index'\">";
    }else{
    echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"REFRESH\" CONTENT=\"0; URL='../koordinator.php?url=index'\">";
    }
    }
    }
    ?>
```

it will only insert the first option, like this:

```
id | alat         | field_usulan
-----------------------------
1  | RJ45         | satu
```

Sorry for my bad language.

Comment: First of all thats a bad idea to insert comma seperated data into the DB. Insert one data per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While inserting, use PHP's implode() function.

```
$usulan = isset($_POST['usulan']) ? implode(',', $_POST['usulan']) : '';
$sql2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_inventaris (alat,usulan)
      VALUES
      ('$alat', '$usulan')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much it's worked very well, thank you :D

Comment: now now, i had another problem -_- as you can see i use `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usulan'][$i])` because i use dynamic table (can add new row), when i change your code from `$usulan = isset($_POST['usulan']) ? implode(',', $_POST['usulan']) : '';`   to     `$usulan = isset(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usulan'][$i])) ? implode(',', mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usulan'][$i])) : '';` i got an error said:
Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in C:\xampp\htdocs\responsive\SIL\proses\p_inventaris.php on line 18, so i hope you can help me too with this. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add all values comma seprated by iterating all over the selected values

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tb_inventaris (alat,usulan) VALUES ";

$values = array();
    foreach ($_GET['usulan'] as $selectedOption){
     $values[] = $selectedOption;
     }

$query .=  "('$alat', '".implode(',',$values)."')";
```

Comment: there's an error said:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$values' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\responsive\SIL\proses\p_inventaris.php on line 29

Comment: @MuhammadFahmy copy my code now ... I was missing `,` before `$values`

Comment: yes, your code works if i change the $_GET['usulan'] to $_POST['usulan'],  but it didn't work when I change it into $_POST['usulan'][$i].. -_-

Answer (score 0):

**ARRAY in database using json_encode**

---

We will use *array* in usulan field, but cause mysql dont have array type.
 
So we must convert array in string using *json_encode* function.
And change string into array using *json_decode* function for display in select form.

---

Table "**tb_inventaris**"

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_inventaris` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `alat` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `usulan` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

---

Form select "**usulan**"

```
<input type="text" name="alat">
<select name="usulan[]" size="3" multiple>
  <option name="satu" value="satu"> satu </option>
  <option name="dua" value="dua"> dua </option>
  <option name="tiga" value="tiga"> tiga </option>
  <option name="empat" value="empat"> empat </option>
</select>
```

---

process php file "**add_process.php**"

```
<?php

    if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {

      include "../conf/koneksi.php";

      $alat = $_POST['alat'];

      // if "$_POST['usulan']" is exist, 
      // convert it into string using json_encode, 
      // otherwise set string blank ("") 
      $usulan   = ( ! empty($_POST['usulan'])) ? json_encode($_POST['usulan']) : "";

      /* Create post */
      $sql  = "INSERT INTO tb_inventaris ";
      $sql .= "( ";
      $sql .= "alat, ";
      $sql .= "usulan ";
      $sql .= ") ";

      $sql .= "VALUES ";
      $sql .= "( ";
      $sql .= "'$alat', ";
      $sql .= "'$usulan' ";
      $sql .= ")";

      mysql_query(sql);

    }

?>
```

display it "**index.php**"

```
<?php

  // check it if not blank,
  // use json_decode and implode functions
  $favorite = ( ! empty(json_decode($row['usulan']))) ? implode(", ", json_decode($row['usulan'])) : "";

  echo $usulan;

?>
```